# Selenium Grid 2 Tests with Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium-grid, automated-tests

I recently discovered Selenium Grid 2. I have used Grid, IDE and RC before, for which writing tests was pretty trivial, especially with the original Grid. (maybe because I never used web-driver?)

Grid 2 documentation is still pretty flaky regarding writing actual tests.

Can anyone get me started with Ruby tests? Perhaps just a simple example would do.

Also what about DeepTest integration with Grid 2... or something similar.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who might be interested, the tests would be in this kind of format:

```
require "rubygems"
require "selenium-webdriver"
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote, :desired_capabilities => :firefox)

driver.get "http://google.co.uk/"
driver.find_element(:id, "lst-ib").clear
driver.find_element(:id, "lst-ib").send_keys "selenium 2 webdriver"
driver.find_element(:xpath, "//ol[@id='rso']/li/div/span/h3/a/em[3]").click
driver.find_element(:link, "Selenium").click
driver.find_element(:id, "q").clear
driver.find_element(:id, "q").send_keys "grid2"
driver.find_element(:id, "submit").click

driver.quit
```

The test is meant to be run remotely, if you want to run it locally then change:

from

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote, :desired_capabilities => :firefox)
```

to

```
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:firefox)
```

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings is a  good reference for all this.